# TerserPlugin Webpack Exclude/Test not working as expectd

Tags: webpack

I want to apply the TerserPlugin for optimization to some of my code and exclude some third party libs (e.g vue) from Terser processing but whatever I try of test, include and exclude doesn't work. 
My code is written in Typescript (only *.ts files no .vue files) and most 3rd party libraries with js in case that matters later.

I tried it with the followig regexes and strings for test, include and exclude of the TerserPlugin like so with the given results:

1.) No test clause specified, no exclude, no include: Terser is applied, e.g. local variables of methods are replaced in my stuff and in 3rd party libs. This is actually odd as `test` default setting is `/\.m?js(\?.*)?$/` according to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin which is untrue for any *.ts file. thus my Typescript files should not be processed by Terser but are

2.) `test: /\.ts$/i` - no terser transformation in my files or third party libs

3.) `include: /\.ts$/i` - no terser transformation in my files or third party libs

4.) `include: /entities/i` - no terser transformation in my files (couple are in a directory names entities) or third party libs

5.) `exclude: /vue/i` - Terser is applied, e.g. local variables of methods are replaced in my stuff and in 3rd party libs

6.) `exclude: "C:\Repositories\m2\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.esm.js"` - Terser is applied, e.g. local variables of methods are replaced in my stuff and in 3rd party libs

7.)  `exclude: "C:/Repositories/m2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js"` - Terser is applied, e.g. local variables of methods are replaced in my stuff and in 3rd party libs

8.)  `exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js')` - Terser is applied, e.g. local variables of methods are replaced in my stuff and in 3rd party libs

That doesn't make any sense to me. Whatever I put in seems to fail, e.g. test and include never seem to be true and thus nothing is processed and exclude also never seems to be true and thus everything is processed. To me this seems like a huge bug - too huge actually for me to believe it is. Any ideas someone?

Here my full Terser config in my webpack config with the place marked where i put the regex expression

```
   optimization: {
          namedModules: true,
          chunkIds: 'size',
          moduleIds: 'hashed',
          removeAvailableModules: true, 
          removeEmptyChunks: true,
          mergeDuplicateChunks: true,
          usedExports: true,
          minimize: true,
          minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
           - place where i put the regex test, exclude condition --
             extractComments: false,
             sourceMap: false,
             terserOptions: {
                output: {
                   comments: true,// to change
                   beautify: true,// to change
                },
                ecma: 6,
                warnings: true,// to change
                parse: {},
                mangle: {
                   eval: true, 
                   // mangle options
                   keep_classnames: false,
                   keep_fnames: false,
                   module: true,
                   toplevel: true,
                   safari10: false,
                },
                nameCache: null,
                ie8: false,
             }
          })],
```

My TerserPlugin version is:  "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.1"

And if it may matter, though I guess not, here my webpack module config:

```
module: {
      rules: [
         {  test: /\.vue$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
         },
         {  test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
            loader: "ts-loader"
         },
         {  test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?$/, 
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[name].[ext]",
            options: {
               outputPath: './m2/fonts',
            }
         },
         {  test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?$/, 
            loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]", 
            options: {
               outputPath: './m2/fonts',
            }
         },
         {  test:/\.sass$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
         },
         {  test:/\.(s*)css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
         },
         {  test: /\.styl$/,
            loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
         },
         {  test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
               loader: 'babel-loader',
               options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is, that `Terser` works on the output chunks and not on the input files.

For example there is a chunkfilter option: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#chunkfilter which states:

> Allowing to filter which chunks should be uglified (by default all chunks are uglified).

The `include/exclude` options are more vague.

So I would conclude in order not to process the vendor scripts - you will have to put them in a separate cache group: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-3 and then exclude this vendor chunk.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped! May open a ticket for the documentation as I personally consider the docu rather misleading

Answer (score 0):

It is an incorrect assumption that the plugin works with .ts files and other *source* files located in the directories where you keep your sources. When plugin starts working, .ts files have already been transpiled into .js files. Please see [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/31) and [that](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/122).

Comment: Thanks. Make sense. Had searched for issues but only on the open ones.